# Using Lsim in Matlab for multi output and multi input systems

Tags: matlab

I have a state space system consisting of 16 state variables, 10 inputs and 18 outputs.

How do I use the [Lsim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/control/ref/lsim.html) command for this system? Particularly, how do i define `u` and `t`, for `lsim(sys, u, t)`.

Thanks in advance for all help!
Amrita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system has 10 inputs and you want to simulate for `Nt` time steps, then `t` should be `1 x Nt` and `u` should be `18 x Nt`, e.g.:

```
sys = whatever;
m = 10;      % num inputs

Nt = 1000;   % 1000 samples
t_end = 10;  % simulate for 10 seconds
t = linspace(0, t_end, Nt);

u = ones(m, Nt);      % a step input on all inputs 
y = lsim(sys, u, t);

% or, e.g.
u = [sin(t); cos(t); zeros(m-2, Nt)];  % sin and cos for the first two inputs,
                                       %  zero for the others
y = lsim(sys, u, t);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped. I want to give it constant inputs for a few seconds of time. My 10 inputs are numbers for example, 10, 23, 34, 45, 56, 5, 4, 3, 2 , 25. How do I write u in this case with same number os time samples. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think the fastest way is `u = kron([10, 23, etc, 25]', ones(size(t)))`, but maybe easier to understand is `u = [10*ones(1, Nt); 23*ones(1, Nt); etc... ]`